# Any general hints on how to prove that two functions$\ f(n)$ and$\ g(m_1,m_2,...,m_{28})$ never have a common natural divisor?

Tags: functions, divisibility, radicals

All the variables are natural numbers. I'm not asking for a proof, since while we simply have$\ f(n)=n^3-n+1$,$\ g$ is a very long sum of cube roots (which contain square roots as well). I'm after general hints, or a general (kind of) procedure if it exists.

Given the sum$\ S$ here: 
[https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/10702119_827019777360332_7596785284762545262_n.jpg?oh=da766c522af76997437a7904407a0824&oe=54B19B3E&**gda**=1425151927_aa94b35de563431507ee468820a8f7a2](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/10702119_827019777360332_7596785284762545262_n.jpg?oh=da766c522af76997437a7904407a0824&oe=54B19B3E&__gda__=1425151927_aa94b35de563431507ee468820a8f7a2) ,

Let$$\ T= S-\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\left(\frac{a_1a_2}{2}-\frac{5}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{27}}+\frac{a_1a_2}{2}-\frac{5}{2}} - \sqrt[3]{-\sqrt{\left(\frac{a_1a_2}{2}-\frac{5}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{27}}+\frac{a_1a_2}{2}-\frac{5}{2}} +\\ \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\left(\frac{a_3a_4}{2}-\frac{137}{54}\right)^2-\frac{1}{729}}+\frac{a_3a_4}{2}-\frac{137}{54}}+\\\sqrt[3]{-\sqrt{\left(\frac{a_3a_4}{2}-\frac{137}{54}\right)^2-\frac{1}{729}}+\frac{a_3a_4}{2}-\frac{137}{54}}-\\ \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\left(\frac{a_5a_6}{2}-\frac{133}{54}\right)^2-\frac{1}{729}}+\frac{a_4a_5}{2}-\frac{133}{54}} -\\\sqrt[3]{-\sqrt{\left(\frac{a_5a_6}{2}-\frac{133}{54}\right)^2-\frac{1}{729}}+\frac{a_4a_5}{2}-\frac{133}{54}}-1. \\ \\g=T^3-T+1$$

I think this will help us. I have found that for natural$\ n$ and real$\ x$,$$\ x^3-x+1=n \implies x= \sqrt[3]{\frac{n-1}{2}+ \frac{\sqrt{69+243(n-2)+81(n-2)(n-3)}}{18}} +\\\sqrt[3]{\frac{n-1}{2}- \frac{\sqrt{69+243(n-2)+81(n-2)(n-3)}}{18}}.$$
I shall note that the$\ m_i$ in the title just stand for $\ 28$ natural variables. Then in the photo I had already used other letters, so it would have been useless to use$\ m_i$ defining$\ T$.

Comment: What do you mean by a function having a common natural divisor?  I'm not familiar with this term....I've only seen divisibility in terms of natural numbers or polynomials or other euclidean domains.

Comment: A useful answer is unlikely, since describing $g$ as an unspecified long sum is not very informative. One can check for the presence (likely) of conjugates in the messy expression.

Comment: @Alan But I am really talking about natural numbers. Since the variables of$\ g$ are related to$\ n$, I can restate my question as: how can I prove (or disprove) that the two functions are coprime for all$\ n$? For example,$a(n)= n$ and$\ b(n)=n+1$ are always coprime.

Comment: Ahh, so we're talking about functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$, and you mean for a common input their output has a gcd of 1?

Comment: @Alan Yes, exactly.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I do have a couple of photos of the sum (I had written it down on another question, but no one answered). Also, yes, there are conjugates. I'll put here the link to the photos in some minutes.

Comment: @Alan Sorry, by the way, actually$\ g$ does go to the reals, so I guess I'm asking: when$\ g$ is natural, is it always coprime to$\ f(n)$?

Comment: @AndréNicolas https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/10702119_827019777360332_7596785284762545262_n.jpg?oh=da766c522af76997437a7904407a0824&oe=54B19B3E&__gda__=1425151927_aa94b35de563431507ee468820a8f7a2

Comment: @AndréNicolas I'll put the link and the relation with$\ g$ in the body.

Comment: It might not be easy to tell when $g$ is a natural, even for something as simple as $g$ being the square root of a cubic in one variable.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yeah... but I have made an edit, check it out.

Comment: If an easy proof is available, it is likely that it will NOT use all those nested roots. Scratch the radicals, and tell us about **the origin** of the numbers $T,S$, $a_i$:s. The formulas for the solution don't appear to be very useful in this case. At least I find them off-putting.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Well, I actually have no information at all about the$\ a_i$ because they really come up in a proof by contradiction, they probably don't even exist. At least, I'm trying to show they don't. Each pair of cube roots is the real solution of a cubic equation (they are many, as you may have noticed), and$\ T$ is the sum of all of these solutions ($\ S$ covered less than required).

Comment: I guess all I'm saying is that if somebody here comes up with an answer it is unlikely to come from a manipulation of that jungle of roots. BTW have you described what you mean by "a natural divisor"?